# SQL Adding Windows Functions as a New Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

So the following Windows function works to get the calculated columns:

```
USE MfgMetrics 
SELECT
[Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG] = LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]),
[Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG] = LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]),
[Calc_Qty_Changed] = 
       (
       CASE 
       WHEN [ORDER NUMBER]!=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) THEN 2
       WHEN [ORDER NUMBER]=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate])
             AND [ORDER NUMBER]!=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) 
             AND [Order_Quantity] != LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]) 
             AND [ACTUAL START DATE] != 0 AND [FileDate] >= [ACTUAL START DATE] 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END
       ) 
FROM dbo.Testing_Table_II
```

But I need to add the calculated columns to Testing_Table_II, and when I try this:

```
USE MfgMetrics 
ALTER TABLE dbo.Testing_Table_II
SELECT
ADD [Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG] AS LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]),
ADD [Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG] AS LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]),
ADD [Calc_Qty_Changed] AS
       (
       CASE 
       WHEN [ORDER NUMBER]!=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) THEN 2
       WHEN [ORDER NUMBER]=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate])
             AND [ORDER NUMBER]!=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) 
             AND [Order_Quantity] != LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]) 
             AND [ACTUAL START DATE] != 0 AND [FileDate] >= [ACTUAL START DATE] 
       THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 
       END
       ) 
FROM dbo.Testing_Table_II
```

It doesnt work... I am not sure how to do an alter or create column when the Windows functions have to be inside a SELECT FROM.

Any help appreciated! I am really new to this stuff, so it could be something small (dumb) that I'm missing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't mix ALTER/ADD schema statements in a query like that. One returns data and the other alters schema.

Comment: Hey Ross Bush! Thanks for your response. So how would I go about populating my Testing_Table_II with the calculated columns if I cant use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- Add the new columns first
ALTER TABLE dbo.Testing_Table_II ADD Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG INT
ALTER TABLE dbo.Testing_Table_II ADD Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG INT
ALTER TABLE dbo.Testing_Table_II ADD Calc_Qty_Changed INT

-- The GO statement (with SSMS) will make the client execute the script as a separate batch
-- So the following UPDATE statement won't fail due to missing table columns
GO 


-- Update the new columns
;WITH NewColumnsValues AS
(
    SELECT
        -- Need to SELECT the primary key values (or any column combination that may work as key)
        [ORDER NUMBER],
        [FileDate],

        [Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG] = LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]),
        [Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG] = LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]),
        [Calc_Qty_Changed] = CASE 
            WHEN [ORDER NUMBER] != LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) 
                THEN 2
            WHEN [ORDER NUMBER] = LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate])
                AND [ORDER NUMBER]!=LAG([ORDER NUMBER],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER],[FileDate]) 
                AND [Order_Quantity] != LAG([Order_Quantity],1,0) OVER (Order By [ORDER NUMBER], [FileDate]) 
                AND [ACTUAL START DATE] != 0 AND [FileDate] >= [ACTUAL START DATE] 
                THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 END
    FROM 
        dbo.Testing_Table_II
)
UPDATE T SET
    Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG = N.Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG,
    Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG = N.Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG,
    Calc_Qty_Changed = N.Calc_Qty_Changed
FROM
    dbo.Testing_Table_II AS T
    INNER JOIN NewColumnsValues AS N ON -- This join has to be by the table's key
        T.[ORDER NUMBER] = N.[ORDER NUMBER] AND 
        T.[FileDate] = N.[FileDate]
```

Comment: HI Ezequiel! Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get that working. I had to change the int to nvarchar since the rest of the testing_table_II values are also nvarchar, and then when I queried the top 1000 of testing_table_II I had to be sure to ORDER BY the keys to get it to correctly calculate. If you have a quick second, can you explain to me why you need the ";" before the WITH? I was reading about that clause online but I hadnt seen that format before. Thank you again for taking the time to help!

Comment: The keyword "WITH" may be used for different statements in TSQL, you can use it to start a CTE (which is this case) or, for example, to establish a table access property inside a SELECT, like in `SELECT 1 FROM myTable WITH (NOLOCK)`. To avoid this confusion SQL Server requires a clear statement-end before starting a CTE, which is why I always place ";" immediately before, just in case. Try to execute, on the same batch, any SELECT followed by a CTE without a semicolon in between the two and you will see that SQL Server will complain.

Comment: Hi Ezequiel- thanks for taking a moment to explain. That helped a ton! Have an awesome day :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to alter the table first then run your selects as an update, joining on field key.

```
ALTER Testing_Table_II ADD 
    Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG AS INT,
    Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG AS INT,
    Calc_Qty_Changed AS INT

GO
```

---

```
UPDATE
    TT
SET
    TT.Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG= TT2.Calc_ORDER_NUMBER_LAG,
    TT.Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG= TT2.Calc_Order_Quantity_LAG
   ...
FROM
    Testing_Table_II AS TT
    INNER JOIN 
    (
       <PASTE YOUR FIRST QUERY HERE>
    ) 
    AS TT2 ON TT.PrimaryKey = TT2.PrimaryKey
```

Comment: Hi Ross Bush! Thank you for your response! This looks similar to the answer above, which did work for me. I appreciate you taking the time to help!